# A query to get the initial value of a custom field in Jira mysql database?

Tags: mysql, jira

We have a custom field which is a dropdown with multiple options. That field is attached to an issue and on initial creation of an issue (after Submit), we'd like to retrieve the value of that field's setting, using a query against the jira db (mysql.)

I emphasize, the field's *initial setting.* Because we can get subsequent changes to field's value through the changegroup tables.

We have tried several queries using the customfield* tables joined to the issue table but nothing.

Again, for example:
we create an issue and leave a drop-down type custom field to it's default setting, say 'CF1'. After submit and before a subsequent change to that field has been made, we want to get that "CF1" value from the DB with a query. The queries we've tried do not work, there doesn't seem to be a chain that links the option value of the field to the issue. maybe there is, but we don't see it.

There is a value we can get in the STRINGVALUE field of the customfield table, but this is a number and it doesn't relate tot eh option setting we're looking for.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need direct access to the DB? Why not to use a post-function from a plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! We've built our own home-grown reporting with the DB. I would consider this post-function though, do you have any samples of that? Thanks again.

Comment: I think you may start with the [Jira Suite Utilities](https://github.com/atlassian/jira-suite-utilities) - they contain several post-functions for custom fields. I know that many other 3-d party plugins exist, but can't recommend most appropriate - please check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN CustomFieldValue CFV ON CFV.Issue = J.ID 
AND CFV.CustomField = {The Custom Field ID for this field}

INNER JOIN CustomFieldOption CFO ON CFV.StringValue = CFO.ID 
AND CFO.CustomValue IN('CF1')

Answer (score 0):

The below query will get the first time a given field was changed for a given jiraissue ID (ID in DB, not the actual JIRA issue key).  Join on jiraissue table to extend this.  ChangeGroup table is made of of all the changes for a given edit in time and the changeitem table is each of those edits.  Basically these two tables are the meta events you see in the All tab at the bottom of a jira issue.

```
select * from changeitem ci 
join changegroup cg on ci.groupid=cg.id
where ci.field like <name_of_your_field> and cg.issueid=<jiraissueid>
order by cg.id asc limit 1
```

Comment: They are not looking for the value of the custom dropdown within the changegroup/changeitem tables as it has been updated.  This is specified in their question as, "I emphasize, the fields initial setting." With this question being over 6 years old I would assume I would not get feedback but it's the default setting for their custom field before any changes are made which would be reflected in the tables you're accessing.  This would actually be reflected in the customfieldoption table.